# How to work with multibyte strings read from a file in Ruby? See inside

Tags: ruby, utf-8

I'm a newbie to Ruby with Perl background. And I got some problems with .reverse of a multibyte string read from an utf-8 encoded file.

Code:

```
#!C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\ruby
puts "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=utf8\n\n" #I execute it via CGI
$: << "."
puts "А это строка".reverse #mb-string output is pretty fine
#but when I do the following, it fails;
file = File.open('test_rb_file.txt','r')
file.each_line {|line| puts line.reverse} #puts line works good, but not puts line.reverse
```

The script itself is in utf-8. The test_rb_file.txt is in utf-8. So, when I try to output a multibyte string - all ok, but when I try to read it from a file and reverse - it fails.

I think, specifying the encoding of the file I read from (test_rb_file.txt) would do the trick, but I don't know how to do that so far. And I maybe wrong about that.

Any ideas to fix the problem? Thanks in advance

**UPD** All fixed, thanks everyone. Following thing sets the encoding of input file and fixes the problem:

```
file = File.open('test_rb_file.txt','r:UTF-8')
```

Comment: What does this have to do with "installing a module"?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change the caption. Fixed.

Comment: What do you mean "it fails"? Please specify HOW it fails.

Comment: @Casper it gives me a complete non-sense, say, �еЀѴнА� instead of йерднА expected. Looks like it reverses a string byte-by-byte not symbol-by-symbol

Comment: please answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

```
File.open('test_rb_file.txt','r:UTF-8')
```

To check encoding of a String `"YourString".encoding`